# For loop with multiple increment statements in Python

Tags: python, c, for-loop

In C, `for` loops can have multiple 'increment' statements.  For example:

```c
int j;
unsigned int r;

r  = 4;  // in reality, a non-trivial initialization

for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++, r++)  {
    if (r == 8)
        r = 0;

    printf("j = %d, r = %u\n", j, r);

    // ... do some work, including continue statements

}
```

In the above loop `j` and `r` are increased simultaneously in every iteration of the loop.

Now I wonder how I can replicate the same in Python.  So far I've found the following solution, which is not as elegant.

```py
r = 4 # actually a complicated initialization

r = r - 1

for j in range(1000):
    r = r + 1
    if r == 8:
        r = 0
     # the rest of the loop
```

The Python version is clearly uglier (particularly because of decrementing `r` by 1 before the start of the loop).

Is there a nicer way to do so?

Comment: use (j + 4) % 8 instead of r

Comment: `j++, r++` is actually a single statement using the comma operator. And in general it makes the code harder to read, not easier... and there's the issue of side effects. Properly written loops have _one_ loop iterator. Then you can have other variables that changes the value too, but you shouldn't mix those up with the loop iterator - it only serves to cause confusion. Personally I would have written your loop as: `for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) { ... r++; }`.

Comment: @NicholasHunter I only showed a MWE.  In reality `r` does not always get initialized to 4.  But it increases by one in lockstep with `j`.

Comment: @Lundin, I thought of that solution.  The issue is that I need to repeat `r++`  before every `continue` statement inside the loop body as well.  (Clearly this applies to both Python and C versions.)

Comment: @kMaster The presence of `continue` inside C programs is a pretty certain indicator of a badly written loop though. It leads to "spaghetti programming" and is one of those keywords we should avoid. `continue` is actually much more harmful than `goto` since the latter could be safely used in a few scenarios, unlike `continue` which always branches non-conditionally upwards.

Comment: If r "increases by one in lockstep with j", then r is dependent on j and should be calculated from j and not a separate variable. If r does not always get initialized to 4, then use (j + c) % 8 instead of r, where c is the initialization value of r. This is also true of the C code.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a simpler way to do this because `j++, r++` occurs only after the first iteration, so typically in Python you emulate that by incrementing at the end of the loop body and before every `break` and `continue`. You could put it at the start of the loop body in an `if j !=0: #dostuff`, but that's a useless check after the first iteration.

Comment: for me your python version is beautiful and readable - and I would use it without trying to find something different.

Answer (score 0):

There is some way to iterate in parallel :

```
from itertools import product
min_i, min_j = 1, 2
max_i, max_j = 3, 4
for i, j in product(iter(range(min_i, max_i + 1)),iter(range(min_j, max_j + 1))):
    print(i,j)
```

The result :

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 2
2 3
2 4
3 2
3 3
3 4
```

If you mean something else, let me know that. I will correct my answer then.